# ASP.NET APP on IIS 7.5 on windows server 2008 r2 - does not log unhandled exceptions

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, asp.net, eventviewer

we have APS.NET application running on IIS 7.5 on Server 2008r2. When developers debug the code in  VS2012 web server the unhandled exceptions are logged in EventViewer but when the app is deployed on production some exceptions did not arrive in EV. I was able to catch the exception with IE11 developer tools but still nothing in the EV. This behavior is relatively new, we are able to get exceptions in EV before.
Can someone point me in the right direction how to configure IIS 7.5 to log unhandled exceptions in EV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can see exceptions in IE11 developer tools, that likely means there are JavaScript exceptions.  JavaScript is executed on the client side, so the server will know nothing about these errors.